# Grub Error, No such device

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2, hard-drive, grubrescue

I installed a new motherboard and processor combo tonight and can not fix grub.

I tried auto grub reinstall in the ubuntu installer rescue system. Nothing.

I tried several of the guides around the web all relating to a live CLI and installing GRUB. I have tried several times and no luck. I get a sucesfull install to sda. minus the sector 32 flexnet error.

When I try to boot I get `error: no such device: (UUID that dosent match)` and then I am at grub rescue. I have 5 drives, all installed in the same order in the BIOS. 4 of them are linux LVM. If i try to boot from one of them I get a nice error message warning me. So I know I am booting to the right device. I just cant get it to let go of the old UUID and find a new one.

I tried:
`sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`
`sudo grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/sda`
I tried several times, several ways. 
I have 12.10

---

this morning I found that even deleting the grub.cfg and running grub-update still pulls the same UUID's. Where are these bring pulled from and how do I update there.

---

further confused. The UUID's in grub.cfg are all right. The one that is coming up at the boot error does not match any of the drives and does not match the ones in the grub.cfg

Comment: I think your not re-installing properly. / can't be your root directory on a rescue CD. It should be something like /media/other_disk/

Comment: The built in rescue on Ubuntu Server actually mounts your root and runs it as the root.

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS had a IDE emulator setting for the sata drives. This caused confusion in grub because It was trying to communicate with the sata directly rather than the emulated IDE.